Help identifying this insulation
Good evening,
Thank you for you help in advance.
There is some insulation in this cupboard and it would be useful to get an inkling of what it is made of. The white one at the side seems to be the same that is at the base. There is a small amount of yellowish insulation.
Sorry the photos I've attached are not too clear.
I was wondering if this is a form of fibreglass or other newer material, or if it looks like asbestos.
Thank you for your help with this.





Looks like mineral wool or fiberglass wool to me on everything shown; they both come in a few colors and they can have a very similar appearance. My guess is fiberglass since it doesn't look quite as rigid as mineral wool would generally be. Feeling it can help determine: fiberglass will generally be quite soft but mineral wool will be a bit more hard and rough.
Asbestos was used in many applications, but I don't ever recall hearing about it in batt form in walls. Couple that with how white the insulation is and I can't imagine that contains asbestos (due to age) If concerned, test it; it's the only way to know.

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate that

Beware to touch this stuff only with gloves, even if it is only fiberglass. The small fibers cause small cuts that itch like hell.

Thank you, appreciate that
